# How to Iterate over a map <string, vector<string>> m

Tags: visual-c++

I need to write a table from a file in a map > m.
I have 3 strings (state, next_states, outputs)

and i want to write them like this (I know it's not correct)

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
//here I have a code, the 3 strings change for every line
  for(j=0; j<m.size(); j++)
  {
     m[i][j] = "state" + "next_states" + "outputs";
  }
}
```

I thought maybe with iterator it would be better but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can iterate through your map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map <std::string, std::vector<std::string>> m =
    {
        {"1", {"a", "b"}},
        {"2", {"c", "d", "e"}},
    };

    for (auto& element : m)
    {
        std::cout << element.first << " : ";
        for (auto& str : element.second)
        {
            std::cout << str << "; ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```